# "What's been up?" meaning

Tags: meaning

I want to know what exactly "what's been up ?" means cause I think it's pretty confusing with "what's up ?". I think it's not exactly the same expression ?

Comment: "What's up?" is asking about you at this current moment in time. "What's been up?" is asking about your situation during some period of time prior to this moment: how have you been in the last couple of weeks, since the last time I spoke with you.

Comment: Native speakers in general (including those who use *"What's up?"* to ask about the *current* situation) don't use OP's cited past tense form. To ask about *prior* events, it's *"What **happened**?"*, *"What's **been happening**?"*, or *"What's **been going on**?"*, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What's been up" is for things that have been happening with the person that you talk to, while "What's up" is about how the person is now.

Well, that's how I think.